# Using conditionalPanel() alongside fileInput() to input different file types based on radio buttons

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Shiny and looking to upload different file types (xlsx, json, csv) to run stats tests on dependent on radio buttons in the UI: I've figured out the interface (I think) but at the moment seem to only be able to upload a file using the first option in the list of conditionalPanels in the UI (have tried shuffling them around and the first option always works, the rest don't). No error messages, just doesn't upload the file.

Here is my ui.R code:

```
        sidebarPanel(
      
          radioButtons("test", "Test type",
                   choices = c(pre_cost = "Pre - cost based KMI",
                               pre_prop = "Pre - proportional KMI",
                               post_cost = "Post - cost based KMI",
                               post_prop = "Post - proportional KMI"),
                   selected = "Pre - cost based KMI"),
          
          # input fields change depending on test wanted
          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.test == 'Pre - cost based KMI'",
            textInput("sheet_name", "Sheet name", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "Sheet1"),
            textInput("uplifts", "Uplifts", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "0.01, 0.3, 0.01"),
            textInput("alphas", "Alphas", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "0.01, 0.2, 0.01")
            ,fileInput("file1", "Choose xlsx file",
                      # select just selected sheet
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      accept = c(".xlsx"))
          ),
          
          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.test == 'Pre - proportional KMI'",
            textInput("baseline_KPI", "Baseline KPI", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL),
            textInput("analysis_KPIs", "Analysis KPIs", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL)
            ,fileInput("file1", "Choose json file",
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      accept = c(".json"))
          ),
          
          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.test == 'Post - cost based KMI'",
            textInput("confidence_lvl", "Confidence level", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "0.95")
            ,fileInput("file1", "Choose csv file",
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      accept = c("text/csv",
                                 "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                 ".csv"))
          ),
          
          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.test == 'Post - proportional KMI'",
            textInput("column_name", "Column name", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = 'impressions')
            ,fileInput("file1", "Choose csv file",
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      accept = c("text/csv",
                                 "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                 ".csv"))
          ),
        ),
```

And the relevant server.R code:

```
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    
    if (input$test == "Pre - cost based KMI") {
        validate(need(ext == "xlsx", "Please upload a xlsx file"))
        df <- read.xlsx(file$datapath, 1)
        output$message1 <- renderText({ "Loaded file"})
    }
    
    if (input$test == "Pre - proportional KMI") {
        validate(need(ext == "json", "Please upload a json file"))
        df <- read_json(file$datapath, simplifyVector = TRUE)
        output$message1 <- renderText({ "Loaded file"})
    }
    
    if (input$test == "Post - cost based KMI") {
        validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
        df <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
        output$message1 <- renderText({ "Loaded file"})
    }
    
    if (input$test == "Post - proportional KMI") {
        validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
        df <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
        output$message1 <- renderText({ "Loaded file"})
    }
    
    if(input$disp == "head") { # disp is an input field head or all for displaying the table
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }
    
  })
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you put unique IDs, it works fine.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      radioButtons("test", "Test type",
                   choices = c(pre_cost = "Pre - cost based KMI",
                               pre_prop = "Pre - proportional KMI",
                               post_cost = "Post - cost based KMI",
                               post_prop = "Post - proportional KMI"),
                   selected = "Pre - cost based KMI"),
      
      # input fields change depending on test wanted
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.test == 'Pre - cost based KMI'",
        textInput("sheet_name", "Sheet name", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "Sheet1"),
        textInput("uplifts", "Uplifts", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "0.01, 0.3, 0.01"),
        textInput("alphas", "Alphas", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "0.01, 0.2, 0.01")
        ,fileInput("file1", "Choose xlsx file",
                   # select just selected sheet
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   accept = c(".xlsx"))
      ),
      
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.test == 'Pre - proportional KMI'",
        textInput("baseline_KPI", "Baseline KPI", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL),
        textInput("analysis_KPIs", "Analysis KPIs", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL)
        ,fileInput("file2", "Choose json file",
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   accept = c(".json"))
      ),
      
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.test == 'Post - cost based KMI'",
        textInput("confidence_lvl", "Confidence level", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "0.95")
        ,fileInput("file3", "Choose csv file",
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   accept = c("text/csv",
                              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                              ".csv")),
        checkboxInput("header3", "Header", TRUE)
      ),
      
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.test == 'Post - proportional KMI'",
        textInput("column_name", "Column name", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = 'impressions')
        ,fileInput("file4", "Choose csv file",
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   accept = c("text/csv",
                              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                              ".csv")),
        checkboxInput("header4", "Header", TRUE)
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("t1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df1 <- reactive({
    req(input$test )
    
    if (input$test == "Pre - cost based KMI") {
      req(input$file1)
      df <- read.xlsx(input$file1$datapath, 1)
    }else if (input$test == "Pre - proportional KMI") {
      req(input$file2)
      df <- read_json(input$file2$datapath, simplifyVector = TRUE)
    }else if (input$test == "Post - cost based KMI") {
      req(input$file3)
      df <- read.csv(input$file3$datapath, header = input$header3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
    }else if (input$test == "Post - proportional KMI") {
      req(input$file4)
      df <- read.csv(input$file4$datapath, header = input$header4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
    }
    
  })
  
  output$message1 <- renderText({ if (!is.null(df1())) paste("Loaded file")})
  
  output$t1 <- renderDT({df1()})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all your inputs to have different IDs, it doesn't matter if they will never appear together. Your file inputs all have the ID file1, this is likely the source of your issue - set them all to different IDs and you should find it working. Of course, you'd need to update the initial data extraction in server.R as well, to pull the relevant file ID based on the radio button.